# Кроссбраузерное использование filter: grayscale, как исправить?

Tags: css3

Нашел на тостере, стиль `filter: grayscale` в таком виде (код ниже), прикрепил, но как-то не кроссбраузерненько...

```css
div#map {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
filter: grayscale(100%), brightness(50%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://a159152.mcdir.ru//sites/all/themes/COSMO/2.1.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 700px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  ymaps.ready(init);
  var myMap;

  function init() {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: [51.767481084662506, 55.113224784597655],
      zoom: 16
    });

  }
</script>
```

Comment: "У меня всё работает" .-. Какие именно браузеры вам нужны и в каких из них не работает?

Comment: Internet Explorer

Comment: Их много. Какой именно?

Comment: упростим... а какой поддерживает?